# MPI : Percolate a subarray from slave processes to update main array in root/master process

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I apologize for the rather long code. Am new in MPI, and am facing issues when I try to parallelize a sorting algorithm. I basically have a huge array of ints , which I have to sort faster by dividing into equal parts to slave processes. Once the slave processes are done, they have to return their sub-arrays to the root process (merged ) which can do further processing. 
Hence : the solution has to be the global array patched with semi-sorted sub-arrays .
 I have already tried looking at previous questions in the forum but am still grounded the whole day.Please dont be too hard on me since am still new in MPI.

```
void Batcher( char *inputFile,   string outputFile, int N  ){

   int initialised;
   MPI_Initialized(&initialised);
   //int rank;
   if (!initialised)
   {
      MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
      atexit(finalized);
   }
   //
   //BEGIN : FILE READING FOR ARRAY
   //
   //Get number of processes
   int world_size;
   int root = 0;
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
   N=world_size;
   //Get the rank of the process
   int rank;
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &rank);

   int *global_array;
   int *sub_array_per_process;
   int element_count;

   if ( rank == root ){
       // ifstream input;
       ofstream output;
       std::ifstream input( inputFile, std::ifstream::in);
       //get number of integers in the file  so they may be populates to array
       int counter=0;
       string line;
       while( std::getline(input,line)){
          if ( line !="")          ++counter;
       }

       int numbers[counter];
       global_array = new int [counter];
       global_array = &numbers[0];


       int current;
       int index = 0;

       //reset read pointer to beginning of input file
       input.clear();
       input.seekg(0, ios::beg);
      //get number from inputfile and add to array numbers 
       while( input >> current){
          numbers[index]=current;
          index++;
          // cout<<((int) a);
       }
      global_array = numbers;

      for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
          global_array[i]=numbers[i];//<<endl;

       for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
          cout<<"global "<< global_array[i]<< " numbers " <<numbers[i] <<endl;


       element_count = counter; 
       input.close();


       /* 
       Send tasks to slaves  */

        int NON = element_count / (N - 1 );
        for(int i=root+1; i< world_size ; i++){
           int start = get_preceeding_ranks(i )*NON;
           //     cout<<"start is "<< start <<endl;
           MPI_Send(&global_array[start], NON, MPI_INT,i, 1 ,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

       }


      MPI_Status status;
      int temp[counter];

   } // End root process operation

    MPI_Bcast(&element_count, 1, MPI_INT,root,MPI_COMM_WORLD );

    int NON = element_count / (N - 1 );
     //Recieve local su-job from root
    if ( rank != root ){
       MPI_Status status;
       MPI_Recv(sub_array_per_process,NON, MPI_INT , root, 1 , MPI_COMM_WORLD ,&status );

    }
    int n_per_small_chunk = sizeof(sub_array_per_process) / sizeof(sub_array_per_process[0]) ;

    oddEvenMergeSort(sub_array_per_process,0, n_per_small_chunk);

    cout<<"After sorting processwise sorting.... "<<endl;
    if ( rank != root ){
         for(int i=0;i<NON;i++)
          cout<<"rank  : "<< rank <<"  data = "<< sub_array_per_process[ i] << endl;
    }
 //   MPI_Bcast(global_array, element_count , MPI_INT,root,MPI_COMM_WORLD );
 //sub_array_per_process = new int[2];

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD  ) ;

   if (rank == root ){
       int start ;
       int sender = -1;
       for ( int i= 0; i< N; i++){
            start = get_preceeding_ranks(i+1 )*NON;
             MPI_Status status;
       cout<<" start = "<<start<<endl;
       sender = i+1;
           MPI_Recv(&global_array[start], NON  , MPI_INT , sender , 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD ,&status );
           cout<<" Received  " << global_array[start] <<" from " << sender <<   endl
           ;
           // MPI_Bcast(global_array, elem , MPI_INT,root,MPI_COMM_WORLD );

        }
         for ( int j=0; j< element_count; j++ )  
             cout<<" Received  " << global_array[j] <<" from " <<sender <<   endl;

   }
   else    {  //Send to root your sub-array..
     // for (int j=1 ; j < N; i++ )
         for ( int i=0;i<NON; i++)
             MPI_Send(&sub_array_per_process[i], NON , MPI_INT,0, 1 ,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

   MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD  ) ;

   for ( int j=0; j< element_count; j++ )  
     cout<<" iOutside  " << global_array[j] <<" from "<<   endl;



   MPI_Finalize();

}

int main() {
  string output;//Dummy

  char* inputFile ="inputsmall.txt";
  int N=0; //Dummy


  Batcher( inputFile,  output, N  );

  return 0 ;
}
```

Since the code is long , specifically am stuck here :-

```
   if (rank == root ){
           int start ;
           int sender = -1;
           for ( int i= 0; i< N; i++){ //get all submitted sub-arrays from slaves. 
                start = get_preceeding_ranks(i+1 )*NON;
                 MPI_Status status;
           cout<<" start = "<<start<<endl;
           sender = i+1;
               MPI_Recv(&global_array[start], NON  , MPI_INT , sender , 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD ,&status );
               cout<<" Received  " << global_array[start] <<" from " << sender <<   endl
               ;


            }
             for ( int j=0; j< element_count; j++ )  
                 cout<<" Received  " << global_array[j] <<" from " <<sender <<   endl;

       }
       else    {  //Send to root your sub-array..
                for ( int i=0;i<NON; i++)
                 MPI_Send(&sub_array_per_process[i], NON , MPI_INT,0, 1 ,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      }
```

The output I get is :-

```
     start = 2
 Received  2 from 1
 start = 4
 Received  3 from 2
 start = 6
 Received  4 from 3
 start = 8
[tux2:25061] *** Process received signal ***
[tux2:25061] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[tux2:25061] Signal code:  (128)
[tux2:25061] Failing at address: (nil)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 25061 on node tux2 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ code.

Comment: noted, thanks. Its only because C and not C++ bindings are used in the code. C++ onesare being deprecated.

Comment: So, element_count appears to be the length of your array, but what is get_preceeding_ranks(i+1) doing? I failed to find its definition. You seem to implement a MPI_Scatter, it would probably be better to use that instead: http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node72.html

Comment: Thanks ,  a lot, went through the tutorial and it helped a lot. My code is now simple and understandable since `MPI_Scatter` and` MPI_Gather`  does all I needed . Your suggested tutorial is similar to what @Pooja suggested : (http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code I can see that when the `rank` is equal to `root`, you're receiving the sorted arrays from the slave processes. The problem lies in your `for` loop. You're trying to receive from from all processes from `i+1` to `N`, while your Communicator has only `N` processes (This is because you've assigned `N = world_size`). Therefore your slaves are `1..N-1`. Hence you need to change the `for` statement as follows:

```
for ( int i= 0; i< (N-1); i++){ //To receive data from process i=1 to i=N-1
```

On another note your code is difficult to debug and manage. You will find it easy to use `MPI_Scatter` and `MPI_Gather` instead. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/)

Comment: Thanks , I seemed to be re-inventing the wheel doing my own `MPI_Scatter` and` MPI_Gather` . Going trhough that tutorial helped a lot.